# Insights FQL returns empty when end_time is current date

Tags: facebook-fql

I have this query:

```
SELECT metric,value FROM insights WHERE object_id=200829446624786 AND
metric IN("page_story_adds_unique","page_impressions_unique",
"page_impressions_organic_unique","page_impressions_paid_unique",
"page_impressions_viral_unique") AND (end_time=end_time_date('2013-03-06')) AND
period=period("days_28")
```

but for some reason the query returns an empty array. I changed the date to last month (2013-02-06) and it returned an array with values for the metrics I asked for.

Can anyone please explain why there were no values when I put in the current month while putting in previous months gives me sufficient values? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the most recent data is always a couple of days old. On my page it is 4 days old.